# kidnapped to be exploited

Tags: passive-voice, clauses

a. They were kidnapped to be exploited as slaves.

b. They were kidnapped to toil as slaves.

Which of the above sentences are grammatically correct?

I think (b) is incorrect, but I am not sure.

Comment: (b) is not ungrammatical, but _to be made to toil as slaves_ expresses it better. Making them work/exploiting them was the kidnappers' intention, not theirs.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are fine.  They both express the intention of the kidnappers.

We can use *to* + infinitive to express intention:

I went to the store **to buy** some bread.